# Can i use microsoft ActiveX object for ajax (Instead of using XMLhttpRequest Object) in IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-9

I am using jquery v1.4.4 for my project. I am facing problems in IE9 with xmlhttpRequest object if any ajax request will be aborted then xhr.status will be set to 0(as expected) in all other browsers but in IE 9 this behavior in not consistent(not set to 0). 
But this is working fine if i use microsoft ActiveX object for ajax. Although latest version of jquery has fixed this issue. I am willing to use activeX object for IE9 instead of upgrading my current jquery version.

Let me know your suggestions about using activeX object for IE9.